# WorkManager workstatus not seeing enqueued job by tag

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, android-workmanager

I use workManager to schedule background periodic job, the job is scheduled and i see from the log that the job runs periodically. However, when i query the job status to see if a job is enqueued, it always return none. Any thought?

```
        Log.e(logTag, "Scheduling a new User Sync Request");
        PeriodicWorkRequest userSyncRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest
                .Builder(userPeriodicSync.class, 900, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .addTag(context.getString(R.string.user_sync_request_job_tag))
                .build();
        workManager.enqueue(userSyncRequest);

        Log.i(logTag, "can i find the scheduled job now???");
        WorkManagerHelperFunctions.isWorkScheduled(context.getString(R.string.user_sync_request_job_tag));
```

here is the function i got online to check the job status

```
public static boolean isWorkScheduled(String tag) {
    Log.e(logTag, "WorkManagerHelperFunctions.isWorkScheduled is called to check tag " + tag);
    WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
    if (instance == null) {
        Log.e(logTag, "workmageer instance is null, returning false");
        return false;
    }
    LiveData<List<WorkStatus>> statuses = instance.getStatusesByTag(tag);
    if (statuses.getValue() == null) {
        Log.e(logTag, "status value for tag " + tag + " is null , returning false");
        return false;
    }
    boolean running = false;
    for (WorkStatus workStatus : statuses.getValue()) {
        Log.d(logTag, "work id: " + workStatus.getId() + " with tag " + workStatus.getTags() + " is in state " + workStatus.getState());
        running = workStatus.getState() == State.RUNNING | workStatus.getState() == State.ENQUEUED;
    }
    return running;
}
```

Here is the log:

09-19 23:46:50.127 17331-17331 Controller: Scheduling a new User Sync Request

09-19 23:46:50.128 17331-17331 Controller: can i find the scheduled job now???

09-19 23:46:50.128 17331-17331 Periodic.WorkManagerHelperFunctions: WorkManagerHelperFunctions.isWorkScheduled is called to check tag userSyncRequestTag

09-19 23:46:50.128 17331-17331 WorkManagerHelperFunctions: status value for tag userSyncRequestTag is null , returning false

Answer (score 1):

`LiveData` does not populate its value immediately - it is asynchronous. This is why `getValue()` returns null immediately after you get the `LiveData`. You must attach an `Observer` to your `LiveData` and wait for the callback:

```
LiveData<List<WorkStatus>> statuses = instance.getStatusesByTag(tag);
statuses.observe(activity, // Or a Fragment
    new Observer<List<WorkStatus>>() {
      @Override
      public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<WorkStatus> workStatuses) {
        // Here is where you can check for status on your work
      }
   });
```

If you're on a background thread, you can use the synchronous versions available from [synchronous()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkManager#synchronous):

```
SynchronousWorkManager syncInstance = instance.synchronous();
List<WorkStatus> statuses = syncInstance.getStatusesByTagSync(tag);
```

But unlike the `LiveData` approach, you won't continue to get callbacks as the status changes - it would only give you a single point in time value.

Comment: Thanks for the help, my class only have context, but the observer require LifeCycleOwner, do you know how i can do that?

Comment: There's a separate `observeForever()` for those cases - just remember that you have to call `removeObserver()` afterwards

Comment: Thanks for quick response and it works! You are awesome!

Comment: Make sure to hit the check mark next to the answer to remove the question from the unanswered questions queue. Best of luck going forward!